# Change the Value of a Label in a page before sending to mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code for sending mail Via button click in asp.net

```
 protected void MailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/AreaManagersMail.aspx"));
        string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string myString = "";
        myString = readFile;
        MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();
        newMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;



        newMail.To.Add("test@test.com");

        newMail.Subject = "Libre";

        newMail.Body = myString.ToString();
        newMail.From = new MailAddress("a@test.com");
        newMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient SmtpSender = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpSender.Port = 25;
        SmtpSender.Host = "elekid";
        SmtpSender.Send(newMail);

        newMail.Dispose();

    }
```

by this i send the formatted aspx as the body of my mail, the problem im encountering is that i am unable to edit the label values inside the mail AreaManagersMail.aspx

in the AreaManagersMail.aspx i tried including this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AccountableAmountLabel.Text = "test";
}
```

but it seems that the page im using is not loading first before sending reading by the stream reader it only sends the empty template i created,

can you recommend how what should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are just reading the ASPX page into memory, and not actually executing the page.

Give this a go:

```
StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("AreaManagersMail.aspx", _writer);

MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();

//other initialisation here    

newMail.Body = _writer.ToString();
```